# Neo4j/Cypher - Return nodes by distinct property values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine a graph filled with data about individuals. Each node has a property named "age". Now i want to return a sample including as many nodes as different values for "age" exist, so if there is one node for each age between 0 and 90, the sample size would be 91.

How can i achieve this through cypher?

What i actually want to do is returning a certain amount of random elements, each with a distinct value for "age", so just obtaining every distinct property value without the corresponding node is not sufficient.

Comment: Is this a common use case you'll have to support, or just a one-off query? You might want to consider a change to your model to better support fast execution of this kind of query

Comment: Also is age static in your data, or is age bound to a birth date, so the age increases as time passes?

Comment: It's a common usecase and the data is static. I did not model the db so changing the data organization would be though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
RETURN p.age AS age, COLLECT(p)[TOINT(rand() * COUNT(p))] AS person;
```

The query collects all the people who have each distinct age in the DB, and picks a random one for each age.

Answer (score 0):

If you have or can gain the ability to change the graph, you may want to extract out individual's ages to :Age nodes (which only works because age is static in your data).

APOC Procedures has a [categorization refactoring procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_refactoring_2) that can help out here.

That way to get a person for each age, you just match on all :Age nodes, and [get one connected node for each of them](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/).

EDIT

As far as making the selection for each age random, we can use cybersam's approach of collecting and grabbing a random index.

With APOC Procedures, we also have the option of using `apoc.coll.randomItem()` to grab a random item from a collection. It's basically doing the same thing under the hood.

The full query (assuming you have distinct :Age nodes (with an "age" property) with relationships to :Person nodes) would look like this:

```
MATCH (age:Age)<-[:HasAge]-(p:Person)
RETURN age.age as age, apoc.coll.randomItem(collect(p)) as randomPerson
```

You mentioned that you need "a certain amount of random elements" each with a distinct age, so we can modify the above query to collect the randomPersons-per-age, and use `apoc.coll.randomItems()` to get however many random entries you need.

```
MATCH (age:Age)<-[:HasAge]-(p:Person)
WITH age, apoc.coll.randomItem(collect(p)) as randomPerson
RETURN apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(randomPerson), {numberOfItemsDesired}) as randomPeople
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. However, that would not guarantee a random result.

Comment: True. Updated my answer to include random selection per age (each person will have a distinct age), and random selection of however many people are needed from the distinct-age-random-persons.